# apache mod_proxy... windows 2008 IIS 7.0 docroot nfs export not working

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, nfs, .net

Gents,
  Unfortunately, I've lost any windows knowledge (if i ever had any)...

We have to mount an nfs export to be served from a few IIS domUs.

Our "developers" wrote this beautiful "thing" that runs on .net... therefore leaving me no choice but to learn IIS, and redirect a portion of the website via:

```
Netscalers -> Apache ->
<Proxy balancer://iis2008>
            #i hate the fucking holidays
    BalancerMember http://iis2008ptc1:80
    BalancerMember http://iis2008ptc2:80
    BalancerMember http://iis2008stc1:80
    BalancerMember http://iis2008stc2:80 
</Proxy>
```

Life was fine until I touched IIS/NFS.

- IIS simply refuses to serve .asp files from an NFS UNC.
- I am able to serve simple .html pages (whew).
- So, I am thinking IIS is trying to write to the export in order to compile the ugly .net code.  Also, I am not able to tweak things like the DirectoryIndex , since its not able to write to web.config on nfs
- If someone could please shine a light on how to fix this?
- The forums are full of people trying to play games, the irc channel on freenode is a joke (literally), and the google searches are coming back with ... not much
- I've spent the whole day working on this, instead I could have been writing my puppet modules.
- No, I can not change to cifs... however, am thinking to either rsync... or a nasty svn export trigger straight from svn.

  XOXO, thanks for help!

Comment: folks at netapp have their head straight ...  but still does not apply to iis unfortunately https://communities.netapp.com/thread/1909

Comment: What happens on a request to to ASP pages - 500 error?  Anything interesting in the windows event log?

Comment: @ShaneMadden,  YEP, 500 error.  Also, if I am logged into the box from console, dragging the .asp pages into firefox loads OK.  Windows error log doesnt exist... I've tried populating the Error Pages and tracking, nothing, zip... as expected

Comment: anyone? ;)  bueller?

Comment: What do you mean by the log "doesn't exist"?  Do you mean there's no errors?  (Check the Application log in event viewer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- OptionA, dont run Windows
- OptionB, dont run windows...
- OptionC, Dont believe in Santa Claus...

  :(

  But if you have to:
  (2008 no longer has UID/GID mapping, this job has been moved to the AD)

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default
>
> Add two DWORD values: AnonymousUid and AnonymousGid and set to your appropriate values in decimal. 
>
> Then restart the ClientForNFS service. (You may need to reboot the server.)
> ```